# If $\text{cov}(a, b) = 0$, what's $\text{E}[b^TCa]$ where $C$ is a matrix of constants?

Tags: expected-value, matrix

Suppose $a\in \mathbb{R}^p$ has mean 0 and covariance $\Sigma_a$, and $b \in \mathbb{R}^n$ has mean 0 and covariance $\Sigma_b$. And $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ is a matrix of constants. Also assume that $\text{cov}(a, b) = 0$.

How can I compute $\text{E}[b^TCa]$? Is it
\begin{align*}
\text{E}[b^TCa] &= \text{E}[\text{tr}(b^TCa)]\\
&= \text{E}[\text{tr}(Cab^T)]\\
&= \text{tr}(C \text{E}[ab^T])\\
&= \text{tr}(C \times 0)\\
&= 0
\end{align*}

Since $\text{cov}(a, b) = 0$, is $\text{E}[ab^T] = 0$ as well? Where $0$ here denotes a $p \times n$ matrix of $0$s.

Comment: Good derivation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your derivation is correct. It can also be written in open form as $$E[b^TCa]=\sum C_{ij}E[b_ia_j]$$
and $E[b_ia_j]$ is $0$ because these are zero-mean random vectors and their cross-covariance matrix is $0$ as well.